# MockMvc testing OPTIONS request

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, cors

Returning to Java/Spring after many years away.  Trying to develop a controller test. I want test a handler for an OPTIONS request, but when I use MockMvc to do something like

```
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder optionsRequest = options("/endpoint/1234");
    optionsRequest.header("Origin", "http://blah");
    this.mockMvc.perform(optionsRequest).
        andExpect(status().isOk()).
        andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "application/json")).
        andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "application/json")).
        andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "application/json")).
        andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "application/json"));
```

with setup

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.controller).build();
```

where `controller` is an instance of my controller, the options handler never gets fired.

In my server startup, we need to do this

```
dispatcherServlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
```

to get the requests handled in the running application.

Is there a way to access the dispatcher servlet in the test setup so I can set the same option?

I have fallen back to setting up mock request/response objects and invoking the methods manually for now....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create your `MockMvc` object with that option

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.controller)
                              .dispatchOptions(true)
                              .build();
```

[Here's](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/) the javadoc.